# Convert string of digits to date, compare against current date

Tags: java, validation, date

Let's say I have a text file with names, an order number, and a date an order was placed. If the dates are in the format of `MMDDYY` (`080315` = August 3, 2015 for example) is there a way I can parse that, convert into date format, then compare it to the current date? I want it so that if they submit a date in this format that is after the current day, it is invalid.

Comment: Is your question "is that possible"? Then the answer is yes. Otherwise your questions seems to be "please write me the code for..."

Comment: You probably need [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Or better yet, in Java8, a `DateTimeFormatter`. Seriously, do some research.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Joda-Time library.

[Joda-Time Website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Then you can do something like.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyy");
Date date = df.parse("070791");
LocalDate ld = new LocalDate(date);
```

Comment: Where do you see the point in using the old `Date` library if OP should use Joda-Time instead?